# Webpack4 configuration with angularJS problem with html loader

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I would like to start application with angularjs bundled with webpack 4. I have output from console:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

My configuration looks like that:

**package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^0.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1"**,
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
```

**webpack.dev.conf.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const {
  prodPath,
  srcPath
} = require('./path');

const sassPreprocessor = {  
  fileRegexp: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
  loaderName: 'sass-loader'
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
      main: `./${srcPath}/index.ts`
  },
  resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, prodPath),
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
      open: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: sassPreprocessor.fileRegexp,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          }, 
          {
          loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: sassPreprocessor.loaderName,
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: false,
      template: `./${srcPath}/index.html`,
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**path.js**

```js
const prodPath = '../dist';
const srcPath = 'app';

module.exports = {
  prodPath,
  srcPath
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

module.exports = env => {
    console.log(`️  running ${env} Mode using ./webpack/webpack.${env}.js ️`);
    return require(`./webpack/webpack.${env}.js`);
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { TodoAppModule } from './src/todo-app.module';
import './styles/main.scss';

export {
    TodoAppModule
}
```

**todo-app.module.ts**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { TodoListComponent } from './todo/todo-list.component';


export const TodoAppModule = angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .component('todoList', TodoListComponent);
```

in **index.html** i inject bundled code using command:
`<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.entry %>"></script>`
and styles using command:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.css %>"`

Can anyone help me with this issue? I've tried to read some configuration documentation on official webpack page, but this isn't work for me. I've saw some examples of configuration with angularjs and webpack, but those solutions don't work here. I will be glad if there are some interesting articles with webpack configuration

Error Message:

```
ERROR in ./app/src/todo/todo-list.component.html 1:0  
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)  
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  
<div>  
    123  
</div>
@ ./app/src/todo/todo-list.component.ts 3:28-65  
@ ./app/src/todo-app.module.ts  
@ ./app/index.ts  
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/index.ts
```

**todo-list.component.html**

```html
<div>
    123
</div>
```

Comment: can you please past the whole error?

Comment: I've edited post above and I've added whole error message